# Expose Spring component to JSP

Tags: java, spring, jsp, autowired

The project I'm working on has a Component which has a restful service injected.
I am trying to call this from a JSP.

So far, I've been able to call my class from jsp with:

```
MyClass mc = new MyClass();

String value = mc.getDetails(id);
```

However, it fails when calling the restful service with a null pointer exception.

```java
@Component("profile")
public class MyClass {

    @Autowired
    private CustomRestfulClient restfulClient;

    public String getDetails(int id) {
        String value= restfulClient.lookup(id);
        return value;
    }
```

I came across this post that seems to ask similar question:
[How to autowired spring service into a jsp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37978687/how-to-autowired-spring-service-into-a-jsp)

However, I only see an explanation of why is not recommended and some other answers proposing some solutions that I'm not sure are valid and secure.

I have tried the following now:

```
 WebApplicationContext wac = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(request.getServletContext());

MyClass mc = (MyClass) wac.getBean("profile");
```

But get a "NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'profile' is defined" error. Also, not sure if this would be a correct approach.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Don't do it, JSP is the *V* in *MVC*, it should handle view operations, not sending RESTful operations

Comment: You don't. Use the Spring MVC framework to create a *Controller* which calls the component and puts the data in the *Model* for rendering by the *View* (your JSP).